How to get the path of the selected file in the current tab of Windows Explorer in rust?
The end goal:

Open Explorer (multiple tabs) in win11.
Select a file
Press the space bar to get the selected file path in your own program

Current progress:
All selected file paths are retrieved.
What my tried:

By IShellWindows

Could not get the path to the file currently selected in the tab of the Explorer.
fn get_select_file_path(hwnd: HWND) -> Option<String> {
    // hwnd 是通过 WindowsAndMessaging::GetForegroundWindow(); 获取的当前活动窗口句柄
        unsafe {
            // 初始化 COM 库
            let com = CoInitializeEx(None, COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
            if com.is_err() {
                return None;
            }

            let hr: Result<IShellWindows, windows::core::Error> =
                CoCreateInstance(&ShellWindows, None, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER);
            // let hr = CoCreateInstance(&ShellWindows, None, CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER);
            if hr.is_err() {
                println!("创建 IShellWindows 失败");
                CoUninitialize(); // 清理 COM
                return None; // 创建 IShellWindows 失败
            }
            let shell_windows = hr.unwrap();

            let mut target_path = None;
            let count = shell_windows.Count().unwrap_or_default();

            for i in 0..count {
                let variant = VARIANT::from(i);
                let window: IDispatch = shell_windows.Item(&variant).ok()?;
                let web_browser: IWebBrowser2 = window.cast().ok()?;
                // 检查窗口是否与当前活动窗口匹配
                let item_hwnd = web_browser.HWND().ok()?;
                if item_hwnd.0 != hwnd.0 as isize {
                    continue;
                }
                let a = web_browser.LocationURL().ok()?;
                println!("web_browser Path: {:?}", a);
                
                // 通过IWebBrowser2获取文件夹视图并获取选中的项目
                let document = web_browser.Document().ok()?;
                let folder_view: IShellFolderViewDual3 = document.cast().ok()?;
                let selected_items = folder_view.SelectedItems().ok()?;
                let count = selected_items.Count().ok()?;
                
                if count > 0 {
                    let item = selected_items.Item(&VARIANT::from(0)).ok()?;
                    let path = item.Path().ok()?;
                    target_path = Some(path.to_string());
                    break
                }
            }
            // 清理 COM
            CoUninitialize();
            target_path
        }
    }


By IUIAutomation

I get the name of the file selected in the current tab of the Explorer , but I can't get its path.
unsafe fn find_tab_items(ui_automation: &IUIAutomation, element: &IUIAutomationElement, file_name: &mut String) -> Result<(), WError> {
        // 查找子元素
        let condition = ui_automation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, &VARIANT::from(UIA_ListItemControlTypeId.0))?;
        let list_element = element.FindAll(TreeScope_Descendants, &condition)?;
        let count = list_element.Length()?;

        for i in 0..count {
            let item = list_element.GetElement(i)?;

            // 尝试获取 SelectionItemPattern
            let selection_pattern: IUIAutomationSelectionItemPattern = item.GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_SelectionItemPatternId)?;

            // 检查是否选中
            let is_selected = selection_pattern.CurrentIsSelected()?;
            if is_selected.as_bool().eq(&true) {
                // 获取文件名或路径
                let tmp_name = item.GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_NamePropertyId)?;
                *file_name = tmp_name.to_string();
                break
            }

        }
        Ok(())
    }

Expected:

Gets the path to the file selected in the current tab in the Explorer.


Windows File Manager has been gone since the year 2000. I presume you mean Windows Explorer instead? It's what IShellWindow interfaces work with, not File Manager.

Yes. Explorer@KenWhite

You edited the title, but the post body still references file manager in several places. :-)

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393

Not work.
Can't distinguish between tabs.

Doesn't QueryActiveShellView return an interface referring to the "current" tab? I don't run Windows 11 so I cannot verify this.

I think you'll have to combine the approaches. From experimentation, the automation interface seems to make the selected tab the first child. So you can get the native window handle from there and use IShellWindows to get the IShellView associated with the same window handle.

In Tauri it needs to be put into a separate thread.
